# R Merging non-unique columns to consolidate data frame

Tags: r

I'm having issues figuring out how to merge non-unique columns that look like this:

| 2_2 | 2_3 | 2_4 | 2_2 | 3_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 3 | -1 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | 3 | -2 |
| NA | NA | NA | -2 | 4 |

To make them look like this:

| 2_2 | 2_3 | 2_4 | 3_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | NA |
| 2 | 3 | -1 | NA |
| 3 | NA | NA | -2 |
| -2 | NA | NA | 4 |

Essentially reshaping any non-unique columns. I have a large data set to work with so  this is becoming an issue!

Comment: @akrun Yes. I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `data.frame` doesn't allow for duplicate column names.  Even if we create those, it may get modified when we apply functions as `make.unique` is automatically applied.  Assuming we created the data.frame with duplicate names, an option is to use `split.default` to split the data into list of subset of data, then loop over the `list` with `map` and use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
 map_dfc(split.default(df1, names(df1)),~ invoke(coalesce, .x))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  `2_2` `2_3` `2_4` `3_2`
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     3    NA
2     2     3    -1    NA
3     3    NA    NA    -2
4    -2    NA    NA     4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`2_2` = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA), `2_3` = c(2L, 3L, NA, 
NA), `2_4` = c(3L, -1L, NA, NA), `2_2` = c(NA, NA, 3L, -2L), 
    `3_2` = c(NA, NA, -2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also using `coalesce`:

You use non-syntactic names. R is strict in using names see here https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html and also notice the explanation by @akrun:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(X2_2 = coalesce(X2_2, X2_2.1), .keep="unused")

  X2_2 X2_3 X2_4 X3_2
1    1    2    3   NA
2    2    3   -1   NA
3    3   NA   NA   -2
4   -2   NA   NA    4
```